# Biblatex: Delete Page Numbers of Quotations Temporary (e.g. for Presentations)

Tags: biblatex, citing

In my document I use `biblatex` and `\autocite`. All of my `\autocite[]{}`come with a specific page number or with a range of page numbers. For my next presentation I would like to use some bits of my text but I would like no page numbers to be shown, e.g. the sentence

```
Der Leser kann Unbestimmtheitsstellen ignorieren oder füllen \autocite[51]{rI68}.
```

will be compiled to

*Der Leser kann Unbestimmtheitsstellen ignorieren oder füllen (Sternberg (1978)).*

instead of

*Der Leser kann Unbestimmtheitsstellen ignorieren oder füllen (Sternberg (1978), **S. 51**)*.

Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

Edit1: In his comment darthbith pointed out that I could do the change manually. However, I would prefer a global change in the preamble in order to avoid trouble when I want to use the presentation on another occasion including the page numbers.

Edit2: Btw, moewe's solution (see below) works for the classes `book` and `article` as well.

Comment: Is deleting the `[51]` not an option? If so, could you explain why that is not an option? A simple find/replace should take care of most cases... Also, I assume the 50 vs. 51 in your question is simply a typo...

Comment: @darthbith, thanks for your comment. If I want to use the presentation on another occasion again and need the page numbers then, I would have to include them again without further ado. A simple global change in the preamble would make things considerable easier. And thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: That's a pretty good reason, you should include it in the question! :-)

Comment: `\renewbibmacro{postnote}{}` could work, but as you didn't provide a minimal example ...

Comment: ... or you might want to try `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{postnote}}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks for your comment. `\renewbibmacro{postnote}{}` doesnt work. I was about to add a mwe, but moewe outperformed me.

Comment: @moewe, thank you so much. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just delete the postnote at every citation with

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{postnote}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{postnote}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \autocite[52]{cicero}
\end{document}
```